# How to show a tooltip with value when mouseover a svg line graph using d3.js?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm using D3.js. I want to show a tooltip with corresponding Y-axis value when i mouseover d3.svg.line().

I tried using this code:

```
d3.svg.line().append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });`
```

but it throws error **has no method 'append'**. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 11):

d3.svg.line() is a line generator; it is not the actual line element. This function is designed to work with an area generator, though you can disable the appearance of the shape within by using "fill:none." For more detailed information, here is a link to its documentation: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line.

The code below creates a path element using the d3.svg.line() generator and then adds a tooltip to the path it generates. This title's text attribute shows the y-value of wherever the mouse is. This is done by using the mouse event "mousemove" which seems to be more what you want instead of using "mouseover." (Mouseover requires you to move in and out of the shape to update the text value, whereas mousemove will change the value even if your mouse moves along the line.)

```
var data = [[{x:100, y:200}, {x:0,y:400}, {x:2, y:300}]];


var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .interpolate("basis"); 

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", 400)
            .attr("height", 400);

var g = svg.selectAll("g").data(data).enter().append("svg:g")
                          .attr("width", 400)
                          .attr("height", 400);

g.append("path")
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("id", "myPath")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 5)
    .attr("fill", "none")    // Remove this part to color the 
                             // shape this path produces
    .on("mousemove", mMove)
    .append("title");

function mMove(){

     var m = d3.svg.mouse(this);
     d3.select("#myPath").select("title").text(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: This code gives only the two parameter X and Y , but i have some array of data that i want to show it on path hover , how can it will possible any idea?

Comment: function mMove can receive a "d" parameter. This "d" parameter is your data element you are hovering.

Comment: This is pre 3.0 code. According to https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Upgrading-to-3.0#svg, should use d3.mouse(this).

Comment: We don't need to hardcode #myPath, and can make mMove reusable. "this" in mMove contains the element, so ("#myPath") can be replaced with ("#"+this.id)

Answer (score 10):

There was a little error in your answer.

```
d3.svg.mouse(this)
```

doesn't work.

The correct answer is

```
d3.mouse(this)
```